# fusedLocationProviderClient not working and MapActivity android

Tags: java, android, google-maps

`fusedLocationProviderClient` does not work.

Included map API and All required dependencies
Here is my function:

```
private void fetchLastLocation() {
       if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]
                {Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},REQUEST_CODE);
        return;
    }
    Task<Location> task = fusedLocationProviderClient.getLastLocation();
    task.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Location location) {
            if(location != null){
                current = location;
                SupportMapFragment supportMapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapid);
                supportMapFragment.getMapAsync(HomeActivity.this);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Here is my `onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap)` function:

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    if(current != null) {
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(current.getLatitude(), current.getLongitude());
        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title("I am here");
        googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
        googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng,25));
        googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
    } /// 
 }
```

Comment: Why isn't your app working? what error log are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say why your app isn't working without providing your full code implementation or the errors you're getting, but I've tested your `fetchLastLocation` and `onMapReady` methods and they work fine on my end. Please run the code below.

```
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderClient;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private FusedLocationProviderClient fusedLocationProviderClient;
    private Location current;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

        fusedLocationProviderClient = new FusedLocationProviderClient(this);
        fetchLastLocation();
    }

    private void fetchLastLocation() {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]
                    {Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 200);
            return;
        }

        Task<Location> task = fusedLocationProviderClient.getLastLocation();
        task.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Location location) {
                if (location != null) {
                    current = location;
                    SupportMapFragment supportMapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
                    supportMapFragment.getMapAsync(MapsActivity.this);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        if (current != null) {
            LatLng latLng = new LatLng(current.getLatitude(), current.getLongitude());
            MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title("I am here");
            googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
            googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 25));
            googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
        } ///
    }
}
```

Also, I recommend you double check that you've set [a valid API key](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/get-api-key) and that you've allowed [location access](https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current#permissions) on your testing device. Hope this helps. In case there is anything in particular that isn't working on your end let me know and I'll modify my answer accordingly.